# Hyper-V on Windows 8 Causing White Noise

Tags: windows-8, hyper-v

I'm running Windows 8 and use Hyper-V to run my Linux and development platforms. However, when I enable Hyper-V in 8 it adds this white noise to my speakers and mic.

Is this a known issue? How do I fix it?

Uninstalling Hyper-V removes this White Noise.

Comment: This almost has to be a hardware-specific thing. Something about either your CPU, motherboard, power supply, grounding or shielding on your case, etc. Maybe take a look at http://superuser.com/questions/298390/why-can-i-hear-the-cursor-flashing-on-my-screen-through-my-headphones, but since it only happens when you enable Hyper-V I'm thinking either higher power draw or just general lack of shielding. Does a higher CPU load also cause white noise?

Comment: I've only ever noticed it with Hyper-V, never with high load. Do you think a soundcard instead of using onboard sound would fix this? I'm only using 21% of my CPU and ~25 of my RAM.

Comment: Maybe - if you have one lying around, it's worth a try or maybe a USB sound dongle thing, or if you can borrow some USB headphones/headset to see if it repro's there.

Answer (score 0):

This is differently a OS bug I have the same problem as you in Windows 8 but have no problems running virtualization in XP, and Win7 and Hyper-V in Server 2008 r2. Also the static doesn't happen at the driver level only at the OS level.
The only fix I was able to find was to remove Hyper-V but now I think I'll just remove Windows 8 all together and use the trusty Win7.

Comment: Perhaps this is beter as a comment as it does not answer the question directly

Comment: I am not so sure. I recently purchased a new soundcard and the issue disappeared. If it was related to the OS or Software, modifying the hardware would not have resolved (or at least masked) the issue.